# Can the "Java console" window be programmatically enabled within a JNLP application

Tags: java, console, jnlp

When running a JNLP application (for example), *"Java console"* is opened, containing the output of the program and a bunch of debug functionality.

Whether the console is opened or not, is determined in the settings in Java Control Panel.

Is there a way to enable & show this Java console programmatically during the program execution?

Or alternatively, is there any way to to enable this Java console during the program execution if it wasn't enabled at the program startup?

(I'm thinking that probably not but if there's a way that could be nice to know)

br, Touko

Comment: No the console does not have the provision to be popped during execution.  What is the problem you are trying to solve, or the feature that you are attempting to offer, by doing so?  It sound pretty dire if you are getting the end user to watch the console.  BTW - 1) Is your app. trusted?  2) Why not implement logging?

Comment: The case being solved is to get the app logs from client in the rare case of something unexpected. 1) App is trusted and 2) saving the logs somewhere will probably be the next option. The purpose was to check out that if this would be possible as it would suit our needs pretty well  so far.

Comment: My recommendation - use a good logging framework.  Have a button on the GUI that will (zip the log &) send it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Thompson's answer is the right way to do this.  My answer is the fast way, if you don't have time to implement a logging framework now:

If you have written your program without logging and you just want to see all those System.out.println messages, you can redirect them all to a text file.
Inside your main method, try this:
     System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("C:/logs/log.txt"));

You might want to include a complete path instead of a local file reference.