# How can I run a jnlp application with console?

Tags: java, console, jnlp

I have a jnlp application that terminate on some systems. I think it is an exception which terminate my application directly. That I want start it with a console window.

Is there an replacement for javaws xyz.jnlp with a java command?

Comment: When I set the following in java control panel-> advanced -> java console -> show console       It launches the console for all the java-programs i start.

Comment: The Java VM terminate before this window is open.

Comment: Slightly of topic, but I tried to debug a similar behaviour where the app closed down immediately, it ended up being this problem introduced in a recent jre http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235872/url-parameters-in-jnlp-href-attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the "Java console" window be programmatically enabled within a JNLP application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722801/can-the-java-console-window-be-programmatically-enabled-within-a-jnlp-applicat)

Answer (score 6):

You can try to set `deployment.console.startup.mode` to `SHOW` to see java console. Either via deployment file (more info: [Deployment Configuration File and Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/properties.html)) or command line parameter:

```
javaws -J-Ddeployment.console.startup.mode=SHOW <JNLP url>
```

Note that, in both cases, it will only work if the JNLP author has not locked the property via `deployment.console.startup.mode.locked`.

If it doesn't help just try to run some Hello World Application with Web Start and connect to it with jConsole. Then you can find somewhere a path to the whole javaws command.